# How to migrate from Feedburner to MailChimp?

Tags: rss, mailchimp, feedburner

I want to migrate my email subscribers from Feedburner to MailChimp but couldn't find any relevant guide.

Is there any way to migrate existing subscribers to MailChimp without requiring them to re-validate their email addresses?

Comment: If you can export the list from Feedburner in CSV/Excel format, you can use Mailchimp to import the list. Subscribers don't have to re-validate their email address. May be this article can help http://blog.mailchimp.com/feedburner-rss-to-email-hack/

Comment: Thanks for the link Yogesh, it looks like the perfect solution. Can you please post this comment as answer so that I may accept it as correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can export the list from Feedburner in CSV/Excel format, you can use Mailchimp to import the list. Subscribers don't have to re-validate their email address. This article will help. 
http://blog.mailchimp.com/feedburner-rss-to-email-hack/